# Parsing CSV using Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, setdefault

I have the following csv file that has three fields Vulnerability Title, 
Vulnerability Severity Level , Asset IP Address
which shows vulnerabilities name , level of vulnerability and IP address that is having that vulnerability.
I am trying to print a report that would list
vulnerability in a column
severity next to it
and last column list of IP address having that vulnerability.

```
Vulnerability Title Vulnerability Severity Level    Asset IP Address
TLS/SSL Server Supports RC4 Cipher Algorithms (CVE-2013-2566)   4   10.103.64.10
TLS/SSL Server Supports RC4 Cipher Algorithms (CVE-2013-2566)   4   10.103.64.10
TLS/SSL Server Supports RC4 Cipher Algorithms (CVE-2013-2566)   4   10.103.65.10
TLS/SSL Server Supports RC4 Cipher Algorithms (CVE-2013-2566)   4   10.103.65.164
TLS/SSL Server Supports RC4 Cipher Algorithms (CVE-2013-2566)   4   10.103.64.10
TLS/SSL Server Supports RC4 Cipher Algorithms (CVE-2013-2566)   4   10.10.30.81
TLS/SSL Server Supports RC4 Cipher Algorithms (CVE-2013-2566)   4   10.10.30.81
TLS/SSL Server Supports RC4 Cipher Algorithms (CVE-2013-2566)   4   10.10.50.82
TLS/SSL Server Supports Weak Cipher Algorithms  6   10.103.65.164
Weak Cryptographic Key  3   10.103.64.10
Unencrypted Telnet Service Available    4   10.10.30.81
Unencrypted Telnet Service Available    4   10.10.50.82
TLS/SSL Server Supports Anonymous Cipher Suites with no Key Authentication  6   10.103.65.164
TLS/SSL Server Supports The Use of Static Key Ciphers   3   10.103.64.10
TLS/SSL Server Supports The Use of Static Key Ciphers   3   10.103.65.10
TLS/SSL Server Supports The Use of Static Key Ciphers   3   10.103.65.100
TLS/SSL Server Supports The Use of Static Key Ciphers   3   10.103.65.164
TLS/SSL Server Supports The Use of Static Key Ciphers   3   10.103.65.164
TLS/SSL Server Supports The Use of Static Key Ciphers   3   10.103.64.10
TLS/SSL Server Supports The Use of Static Key Ciphers   3   10.10.30.81
```

and I would like to recreate a csv file that uses Vulnerability Title tab as the key and creates a second tab called Vulnerability Severity Level and last tab would contain all the ip addresses that has the vulnerabilities

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict
import glob
x= glob.glob("/root/*.csv")

d = defaultdict()
n = defaultdict()
for items in x:
        with open(items, 'rb') as f:
                reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
                for row in reader:
                        a = row["Vulnerability Title"]
                        b = row["Vulnerability Severity Level"], row["Asset IP Address"]
                        c = row["Asset IP Address"]
        #               d = row["Vulnerability Proof"]
                        d.setdefault(a, []).append(b)
        f.close()
pprint(d)
with open('results/ipaddress.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for key, value in d.items():
                for x,y in value:
                        n.setdefault(y, []).append(x)
#                       print x
                        writer.writerow([key,n])

with open('results/ipaddress2.csv', 'wb') as csv2_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv2_file)
        for key, value in d.items():
             n.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
             writer.writerow([key,n])
```

Since I cant explain very well. let me try to simplify

lets say I have the following csv

```
Car model   owner
Honda   Blue    James
Toyota  Blue    Tom
Chevy   Green   James
Chevy   Green   Tom
```

I am trying to create this csv as the following:

```
Car model   owner
Honda   Blue    James
Toyota  Blue    Tom
Chevy   Green   James,Tom
```

both of the solutions are correct.
here is my final script as well

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=['Vulnerability Title', 'Vulnerability Severity Level','Asset IP Address'])
#print df
grouped = df.groupby(['Vulnerability Title','Vulnerability Severity Level'])

groups = grouped.groups
#print groups
new_data = [k + (v['Asset IP Address'].tolist(),) for k, v in grouped]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['Vulnerability Title' ,'Vulnerability Severity Level', 'Asset IP Address'])

print new_df
new_df.to_csv('final.csv')
```

thank you

Comment: Could you give in an example, the structure of the final csv you are trying to create? That would be really helpful

Comment: thank you picmate. I edited the questions with more details? let me know if I should add more info.

Comment: You are welcome, the last edit especially is great. Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer, let me know whether that works. For your car example, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When manipulate structured date, especially large data set. I would like to suggest you to use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

For your problem, I will give you an example of pandas groupby feature as solution. Suppose you have the data:

```
data = [['vt1', 3, '10.0.0.1'], ['vt1', 3, '10.0.0.2'], 
        ['vt2', 4, '10.0.10.10']]
```

The pandas to operate date is very fensy:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['title', 'level', 'ip'])
grouped = df.groupby(['title', 'level'])
```

Then

```
groups = grouped.groups
```

will be a dict that is almost you need.

```
print(groups)
{('vt1', 3): [0, 1], ('vt2', 4): [2]}
```

`[0,1]` represents the row label. Actually you can iterate on these groups to apply any operation you want. For example, If you want to save them into csv file:

```
new_data = [k + (v['ip'].tolist(),) for k, v in grouped]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['title', 'level', 'ips'])
```

Let's see what is new_df now:

```
  title  level                   ips
0   vt1      3  [10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2]
1   vt2      4          [10.0.10.10]
```

That's what you need. And finally, save to file:

```
new_df.to_csv(filename)
```

I strongly suggest that you should learn pandas data manipulation. You may find that was much easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Answer considering your car example. Essentially, I am creating a dictionary which has the car brand as the key, and a two element tuple. The first element of the tuple is the color and the second, a list of owners.):

```
import csv

car_dict = {}
with open('<file_to_read>', 'rb') as fi:
    reader = csv.reader(fi)
    for f in reader:
        if f[0] in car_dict:
            car_dict[f[0]][1].append(f[2]) 
        else:
            car_dict[f[0]] = (f[1], [f[2]])

with open('<file_to_write>', 'wb') as ou:
    for k in car_dict:
        out_string ='{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(k, car_dict[k][0], ','.join(car_dict[k][1]))
        ou.write(out_string)
```

Comment: import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=['Vulnerability Title', 'Vulnerability Severity Level','Asset IP Address'])
#print df
grouped = df.groupby(['Vulnerability Title','Vulnerability Severity Level'])

groups = grouped.groups
#print groups
new_data = [k + (v['Asset IP Address'].tolist(),) for k, v in grouped]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['Vulnerability Title' ,'Vulnerability Severity Level', 'Asset IP Address'])

print new_df
new_df.to_csv('final.csv')